# Is there a way to temporarily pause iCloud sync of photos?

Tags: ios, icloud, photos

Is there a way to temporarily pause the syncing of photos over iCloud on an iOS device? Sometimes I'm on a 3G connection and don't want to waste my quota syncing photos or sometimes I want to speed up the download of other files by pausing iCloud. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to pause it, but you can disable it temporarily. The only downside is that you will have to redownload all the pictures when it is re-enabled. To disable cell data for photo stream, you can go into Settings>Cellular and find the Photos app. Simply turn it off.

Comment: Wow this sucks (on Apple's part). I've been to a number of conventions where the WiFi gets totally crippled to the point it's unusable because 100s of iOS devices are uploading/syncing at the same time as soon as they are connected to a WiFi there. Wtf.

Answer (score -2):

I had a slightly different situation...my wifi is shared with macbook air (laptop), 2 iPhones and an iPad.  I upgraded my storage plan with iCloud and a lot of syncing was going on so I couldn't do much else online.  [This article helps pause iCloud syncing on a mac](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6983028?start=0&tstart=0).  I then put the phones and tablet into airplane mode.  That freed up the wifi so I could at least work on my laptop.  Before I go to sleep for the night I will re-activate everything and hopefully syncing will pick up where it left off and be done by morning.